# Apple in-app recurring payments — what happens if authorized credit cards balance is zero?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, credit-card, recurring-billing

From documentation it is not clear if Apple keeps trying to renew subscription after first unsuccesfull attempt (not enough money on the card, eg).

Should I keep verifying receipt validity if it is not renewed in one hour after subscription is over? In one day? One year?